# Problema al cargar librerías de JQuery y Bootstrap cuando agrego mi aplicación en el servidor iis 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, iis

Tengo un problema estoy desarrollando una aplicación en una plantilla **Aplicación web asp.net(.net framework) web forms Vacía** y al hacer las pruebas de debugger dentro de el **Visual Studio 2019** me funciona perfecto todas las plantillas, que sucede yo estoy intentando montar esta aplicación dentro del servidor **iis 10** y que mi pagina de inicio sea **login.aspx**  esta pagina la estoy realizando con librerías bootstrap 4 (esto ya lo logre).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema recae que cuando yo intento examinar mi aplicación desde el iis, luego de montarla no me levanta ninguna librería y el login.aspx se ve esta forma y me lanza este error por consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ERRORES**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo no se si esto es debido a que estoy llamando mal mis librerías de bootstrap 4 o se debe hacer un cambio dentro de iis he buscado mil soluciones y no hayo una concreta para este problema. dejare mi código de mi pagina de login.aspx aquí abajo.

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ejemplo_Web.Pages.Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Inicio de sesión</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/bootstrap_4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-- CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/signin.css" type="text/css" />>
    <!-- JQUERY Y AJAX -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/JQuery_y_Ajax/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <%--<script src="--https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-- Bootstrap core Js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/bootstrap_4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DATATABLES js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <style>
         #Image2 {

             Height:143px;
             Width:961px;
         }
         #Image3{
         Height:29px;
         Width:959px;
         }
    </style>
</head>
  <body class="text-center"> 
        
      <br />
         <br />
             <br />
                 <br />
                     <br />
                         <br />
  <form class="form-signin">
  <%--<img class="mb-4" src="" alt="" width="72" height="72">--%>
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Ingrese los datos</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Cédula</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="location.href = '../Pages/Solicitud_Vacaciones.aspx'" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2020</p>
</form>
      <br />
         <br />
             <br />
                 <br />
                     <br />
                         <br />
        
</body>
</html>
```

**Esta es una plantilla de ejemplo del problema que tengo**.

Comment: no sé si `assets` es un directorio virtual, sea cual fuera el caso, configuraste bien el acceso para usuarios anónimos a `/assets/`??

Comment: assets es un directorio local dentro de mi solución, como se hace eso que mencionas de los usuarios anónimos , dentro de mi administrador de iis y seleccionando mi aplicación web fui a autenticación y modifique usuarios anónimos a que fuera identidad del grupo de aplicaciones es eso o es otra cosa?